# Container for in-memory representation of a DB table

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, containers

Let's say I have a (MySQL) DB. I want to automate the update of this database via an application, that will:

```
1. Import from DB
2. Calculate updated data
3. Export back updated data
```

The timing is important, I don't want to import *while* calculating, in fact I don't want any queries then; I want to import (a) table(s) as a whole, *then* calculate. So, my question is, if a row is represented with an instance of a class, then what container do I put these objects into?

A vector? A set? What about ordered vs. unordered? Just use what seems best for my case according to big O times? Any special traps to fall into here? Is this case no different than with data "born in memory", so the only things to consider besides size overhead are "do I want the lookup or the insertion to be faster" ?

Probably the best route is to use some ORM, but let's say I don't want to.

I've seen some apps use `boost::unordered_set`, and I wondered, if there is a particular reason for its use...

I use a jdbc-like interface as the connector (`libmysqlcpp`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that the container you have to use can be guessed with so few information. It mainly depends of the data size, type and the algorithm you will run.

But my main concern over such a design is that it will quickly choke your network or your base and database. If you have a big table you'll:

- select all the data from the table
- retrieve all the data over the network
- process on you machine part (some columns ?) or the entirety of the data
- push the data over the network
- update your rows (or erase/replace maybe)

Why don't you consider working directly on the mysql server ? You create your [user defined function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15643/MySQL-User-Defined-Functions) that work on the directly data, saving the network and even taking advantage of the fact that mysql is built to handle gigantic amount of data, quantity that an in-memory container is not built to handle.

Comment: What if the calculation is fairly complex? A few hundred MB serialized input file is used and after parsing, calculation is performed using data we have so far (coming from DB) and new data (coming from the input file). The DB then needs to be updated (maybe on some columns, maybe multiple tables) with the output of the calculation. I want to do this in cpp, because I don't know much about databases, and I'm not sure if user defined functions in a DB are meant to do this.

Comment: DB is estimated to be ~25 tables, ~10M entries in the largest. Input files are up to ~1GB max, processing time in cpp is ~2-3 hours. Import/export times are tested with similar table sizes, and never went above 20-30 minutes which is acceptable in this case. (NOTE: these are estimates, no code is written yet, this is the design phase)

Comment: Maybe there is real reasons to use your proposed design. I'm seeing only a small part of your problem. :) From what you're saying now I would process the data from the file, inject it into the DB and "reconciliate" it in the DB. Your user defined proc can be done in c++, and there is maybe more that can be done in C++. The only concern I would have with such a design would be loading the CPU of the DB box a bit too much if the users are still querying it.

Comment: Please elaborate, you mean omitting import, somehow processing input file without knowing past data, then exporting and updating it on DB server?

Comment: I mean processing your new data to insert it in some dedicated schema/table and then do the calculation/update of your "real" tables on the database.